# Splitting multibyte I/O on x86

Tags: assembly, io, x86, hardware

On the x86 platform you can read/write to 2/4 consecutive I/O ports using the in/out instructions of the appropriate word size (or their string opcode analogues which can be used with rep-prefixes). I encountered a piece of hypervisor code that emulates I/O by parsing the opcode the guest attempted to execute, then proceeded to fragment multibyte I/O to byte I/O, performed each byte I/O separately, and unified the results to return them to the guest.

I was wondering how much of difference there is between that and performing the multibyte I/O directly from the hardware's PoV (or any other aspect I hadn't thought of), because I can't imagine the two being equivalent and I'm a bit baffled.

Comment: IIRC they are not equivalent. I remember some datasheet (or Ralf Brown *PORT* files) explicitly stating the size of the IO operation for a correct behavior. Unfortunately I can't recall what exact devices were.